How do I reallocate bad sectors on a hard drive without it having a partition
I was partitioning my hard drive when it broke unexpectedly and reported a lot of bad sectors. I want to reallocate the bad sectors and still use the good ones, but all other guides require the hard drive to have a partition to operate on which I don't. Also, because there are too many bad sectors it will not let me reinitialize the drive giving the error: "Data Error: Cyclic Redundancy Check"

Reallocation should be transparent and happen on any writes to the drive, including partitioning and any writes to unallocated areas. If you are getting errors on creating a partition then it may be that there are no spare sectors available in the area of the drive used for that purpose. If so the drive should probably be considered to be on borrowed time and should be replaced.


Also, because there are too many bad sectors it will not let me reinitialize the drive giving the error: "Data Error: Cyclic Redundancy Check"

Well, that strongly implies you have no more spare sectors to reallocate so there's nothing you can do with it anymore.

but all other guides require the hard drive to have a partition to operate on which I don't.

For reallocation via the HDD's firmware, that's not needed – anything you can do with a partition, you can also do with the entire disk directly. I suspect those guides require you to have a filesystem within that partition, for reasons explained below.
Generally the HDD's firmware will reallocate sectors automatically as soon as the OS attempts to write to them, without any manual action needed. There are various tools (any "bad sector test" tool might work) which write something to every sector of the disk, forcing it to preemptively reallocate bad sectors.
Note though that reallocation is not the same as avoiding those sectors completely. The HDD will only reallocate a sector by redirecting it to a spare sector in another physical location, and if you run out of spares, you can't do any more reallocations.
So if what you're asking about is avoiding the bad sectors without reallocation, that's generally not something HDDs support; they don't have an option to outright remove bad sectors by reducing capacity. (At least not a user-visible option.) Such removal therefore needs to be done at filesystem level – not at disk or partition level, but by configuring the filesystem to avoid certain sectors for data storage, while the sectors themselves will remain visible.
That's probably why the tutorials require a partition; not because of the partition in itself, but because they require the filesystem that you put inside, as the process they explain configures a filesystem.

Do you have any suggestion on how to configure the filesystem to avoid the bad sectors?
